Can a 13th Age monk use both "General Slays the Hordes" attacks against just one target enemy?
In the 13th Age Monk Adventurer Form "Way of the Metallic Dragon", the finishing attack (General Slays the Hordes) specifies the Targets as
"Up to two enemies; choose one for the first attack and the other for the second attack"
Even if there are two enemies, there is clearly enough time to apply both attacks.  The fact that it doesn't require two enemies indicates that General Slays the Hordes could be used against one target enemy.
When using this finishing attack against just one enemy, does this mean both of the attacks can be applied in succession to the one enemy?
On the other hand, is there anything about this finishing attack that implies that one can only use both attacks if they are against different enemies and that only one attack could be applied to a single enemy target?  And if only one attack is possible, could either attack be used? For example, could one expend the first attack into the air to no purpose as if there were some other target and then apply the second attack (which includes fire damage) to the single enemy target?
Since it would certainly be possible with two enemies to miss the first and hit with the second, I don't see anything in the text that would exclude choosing to skip the first attack (or discharge it to no effect into the air as if there was another pretend target) and apply the second attack to the target enemy.  And if that is so, what is to exclude applying both the first and second attack toward the same single enemy when there is only one?
Does anyone know of a clarifying indication one way or the other anywhere in the source material?

There are two things to note here. The first is that the Way of the Metallic Dragon starts with the Opening Attack "Bronze Thwarts An Army," which requires that you be engaged with two enemies when you use it. Although you can shift to General Slays The Hordes after any Flow Attack, it's useful to understand the intent of the style.
The other is the language being used: When the text says "one" and "the other," the implication is that they are not the same. You do not have to strike two enemies, but the enemies being struck must be different.
Likewise, there is no provision for intentionally making an attack to no effect. (13A Core Rules, p.167, "You declare which attack you are using and pick its target or targets, then roll the d20 for each one to find out if you hit. The attack will indicate what happens to a target that you hit (and sometimes one that you miss).")

My original hope had been that someone might be aware of some additional clarification somewhere in the source material where more was said about the intended interpretation.  So far, that has not appeared.  If we must derive the most plausible interpretation from only the text we have, one other valuable clue to the author's intention is to consider what the author could have written, but chose not to write.  What is missing that could have been there, if the author had wanted and intended it?
What we already know:

We know that any Finishing Attack can be used following any combination of an Opening Attack and a Flow Attack.
We know explicitly that this Finishing Attack can legitimately be used with either one enemy or two.
We also know explicitly the procedure when there are two targeted enemies.

The question we are answering: What should a monk do when there is only one targeted enemy?
There are only two possible categories of answers.

Edited Version: The monk must execute an edited version of the "Way of the Metallic Dragon" in which one of the two attacks has been omitted.
Full Version: The monk still executes the full, unrevised version of the "Way of the Metallic Dragon", including both attacks even if there is only one targeted enemy.

Consider possibility #1 of using an edited version.
If that had been the intention of the form author, then the description as written would have a serious problem.  It doesn't address at all an obvious subsequent question.
How should the "Way of the Metallic Dragon" be revised so that it has only one attack for the one enemy?

1a: The first attack must be omitted and the monk should only do the second attack.
1b: The second attack must be omitted and the monk should only do the first attack.
1c: The monk is free to omit either attack and may use either of the two possible attacks however they choose on a case by case basis.

Option 1c would clearly be one reasonable possibility.  Realistically, if the monk is able to do both attacks (when there are two enemies), then certainly the monk has learned how to execute each attack against an enemy.
However, the most important thing to notice is what the form does not say.  If the author had intended that the monk must execute a revised Finishing Attack that only includes one of the attacks, then with that in mind it would be reasonable to expect they would have addressed how the edit should be made to omit one of the attacks.  But the author does not deal with or even touch upon that obvious question -- plausibly because revising the Finishing Attack to omit one of its attacks isn't the intended interpretation they had in mind.
Consider possibility #2 of using the full version with both attacks and no revisions.
Is it most reasonable to think that the monk (who is able to perform both attacks in sequence against two side-by-side enemies) cannot perform more than one of the two attacks against a single enemy?

2a: If we try to hold onto the idea that only one of the two attacks could be applied to a single enemy, then to execute the full Finishing Attack would require applying one of the two attacks to an imaginary enemy to no purpose or effect.  While that is certainly physically possible (people normally practice and demonstrate forms against imagined enemies all the time), that would be pointless and unrealistic in any real combat situation.  Plus, as Jadasc pointed out, there isn't a game reason or mechanic for doing so.  Most importantly, nothing in the description imposes the supposed limitation of at most one attack against a single enemy.  The author could have added that limitation, if that was the intent, but it simply is not there.
2b: The final remaining possibility is that the monk executes the full, unrevised Finishing Attack with the same sequence of two attacks by applying both attacks to the one and only targeted enemy.  Again, if we suppose that the monk is able to do both attacks in sequence against two side-by-side enemies, then we don't have any reason to assume the monk is unable to apply both attacks in sequence against a single enemy.

Conclusion
If all we have to go on is the words in the description of the "Way of the Metallic Dragon" Finishing Attack, then the silences are significant indicators.  If an interpretation leads to the conclusion "We are obviously missing essential information on how to implement that interpretation", then that is probably not the intended interpretation.
The only interpretation that does not run into that problem is the one in which the monk continues to execute the full "Way of the Metallic Dragon" Finishing Attack, applying both attacks to the same enemy in the case that only one enemy is targeted.
